# Google Apps Script Class UrlFetchApp to fetch a web page which url does't start with "http://"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using the Class UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script to fetch a web page which URL does't start with "http://", but I have no success. The purpose is automatize some processes.

When I open the link in a Web browser, it works perfectly. But, when I use the fetch(url) function, I get the exception:

Address unavailable: http://xxxx.xxx.xx

Apparently the request inserts "http://" before "xxxx.xxx.xx", but this link does not exist. The code I use is:

```
var Page_Link = "xxxx.xxx.xx"  // The URL Doesn't start with 

function UrlFetchApp(){
  try{
    Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(Page_Link));
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to perform the fetch with the correct link?

Comment: From your use of UrlFetchApp, I'm guessing you're using Google Apps Script. Please do [edit] your question if that is not the case.

Comment: Yes, I am using using Google Apps Script. I forgot to specify that

Comment: If the page is not http, what is it? ftp? [UrlFetchApp works over HTTP or HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: You can't access local pages from the internet.

Comment: I think that I was wrong. I assumed that the url http://xxxx.xxx.xx doesn't exist due to exception "Address unavailable: http://xxxx.xxx.xx obtained using the fetch method. But using curl http://xxxx.xxx.xx on my terminal I obtain the expected result. Probably the administrator of the server blocked IP addresses of Google. Thank you very match with the help.